# Перегрузка += и == либо !=

Tags: перегрузка-операторов, c#

Почему перегрузка += возможна только через +, но при этом == и != перегружаются по отдельности? Ведь, казалось бы, всё должно быть в точности до наоборот.

За счёт ненадобности выделять дополнительную память += почти всегда можно реализовать эффективнее, чем +. Но вот примера, где реализации == и != должны отличаться чем-нибудь, кроме инвертирования результата Equals(), я придумать не могу.

Comment: Про == и != - это сделано, чтобы кто-нибудь облажался ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ходу так:
1) == и != перегружаются по отдельности, как минимум, потому, что нет гарантий, что результат будет bool.
2) += перегружается через +, так как другой возможности его перегрузки нет: все операторы должны быть static.

Comment: == и != обязаны иметь bool результат.

Comment: @AlexeyM с чего бы это?
Вот к примеру visual studio 2008 спокойно компилирует подобные вещи:
www.pastie.org/2387016

Comment: @Kn793 действительно, в спецификации шарпа (Ecma-334, 17.9.2) есть лишь требование, чтобы возвращаемые типы == и != совпадали. Однако сложно представить, когда может понадобиться возвращать что-либо, кроме bool'а.

Answer (score 0):

Может такой пример сработает? Два хэша равны - это не значит что закодированное равно. А если хэши не равны - то закодированное различно.

Comment: А += - это (видимо исторически, со времен С) синтаксическое сокращение, а не разная операция с +.

Comment: Не понимаю чем этот пример здесь поможет. Ну реализуем мы Equals с передпроверкой хешей на различие, а == и !=, как обычно, через equals.

Comment: Оверхед :)

Другой пример - логгирование действий. Логгирование += и + будет законно одинаковым, а логгирование сравнений будет выдавать разное. Все это может быть полезно в аспектно-ориентированном программировании.

Эти операции могут быть различными еще по причине того, что сравнение _объектов_ (как в каноническом ООП объекты - отражение объектов реального мира) могут не подчиняться бинарной логике. 
Например, здание. Одно здание равно другому, если их проекты одинаковые. И одно здание не равно другому, если они имеют разные адрес. Это не совсем правильный пример, но думаю подобное возможн